# In the context described are unused modules excluded from the build?

Tags: angular

In order to follow good practices and keep a project organized I have created a shared module that contains declared and imported: components, directives and pipes. Import and export `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` as well as other third-party modules

Shared module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule,
    TranslateModule,
    PrimengModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormlyModule,
    TranslateModule,
    PrimengModule,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Eventually each feature module imports this shared module

Among these modules that it exports is one that is in charge of exporting all the `primeng modules`.

```
const formModules: any[] = [
  CalendarModule,
  AutoCompleteModule,
  ButtonModule,
  CascadeSelectModule,
  CheckboxModule,
  ChipsModule,
  ColorPickerModule,
  DropdownModule,
  EditorModule,
  InputMaskModule,
  InputSwitchModule,
  InputTextModule,
  InputTextareaModule,
  InputNumberModule,
  KnobModule,
  KeyFilterModule,
  ListboxModule,
  MultiSelectModule,
  PasswordModule,
  RadioButtonModule,
  RatingModule,
  SelectButtonModule,
  SliderModule,
  TreeSelectModule,
  TriStateCheckboxModule,
  ToggleButtonModule,
];

const buttonModules: any[] = [ButtonModule, SplitButtonModule, SpeedDialModule];

const dataModules: any[] = [
  TableModule,
  DataViewModule,
  ScrollerModule,
  OrderListModule,
  OrganizationChartModule,
  PaginatorModule,
  PickListModule,
  TreeModule,
  TreeTableModule,
  TimelineModule,
  VirtualScrollerModule,
];

const panelModules: any[] = [
  AccordionModule,
  CardModule,
  DividerModule,
  FieldsetModule,
  PanelModule,
  SplitterModule,
  ScrollPanelModule,
  TabViewModule,
  ToolbarModule,
];

const overlayModules: any[] = [
  ConfirmDialogModule,
  ConfirmPopupModule,
  DialogModule,
  DynamicDialogModule,
  OverlayPanelModule,
  SidebarModule,
  TooltipModule,
];

const fileModules: any[] = [FileUploadModule];

const menuModules: any[] = [
  BreadcrumbModule,
  ContextMenuModule,
  DockModule,
  MenuModule,
  MenubarModule,
  MegaMenuModule,
  PanelMenuModule,
  SlideMenuModule,
  StepsModule,
  TabMenuModule,
  TieredMenuModule,
];

const chartModules: any[] = [ChartModule];

const messageModules: any[] = [MessagesModule, ToastModule];

const mediaModules: any[] = [CarouselModule, GalleriaModule, ImageModule];

const dragDropModules: any[] = [DragDropModule];

const miscModules: any[] = [
  AvatarModule,
  BadgeModule,
  BlockUIModule,
  ChipModule,
  InplaceModule,
  ScrollTopModule,
  SkeletonModule,
  ProgressBarModule,
  ProgressSpinnerModule,
  TagModule,
  TerminalModule,
];

const directivesModules: any[] = [
  DeferModule,
  FocusTrapModule,
  StyleClassModule,
  RippleModule,
  AutoFocusModule,
  AnimateModule,
];

const utilityModules = [OverlayModule];

const primengModules: any[] = [
  ...formModules,
  ...buttonModules,
  ...dataModules,
  ...panelModules,
  ...overlayModules,
  ...fileModules,
  ...menuModules,
  ...chartModules,
  ...messageModules,
  ...messageModules,
  ...mediaModules,
  ...dragDropModules,
  ...miscModules,
  ...directivesModules,
  ...utilityModules,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [...primengModules],
  exports: [...primengModules],
})
export class PrimengModule {}
```

The project is in early stage and only a few of these primeng modules are used. My question is: In this context, will the build created include all unused primeng modules?

Thanks in advance